# How to config dask to connect to remote SSH server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, permissions, dask

```
from dask.distributed import Client, SSHCluster
cluster = SSHCluster(["localhost", "192.168.x.x"],
connect_options={"known_hosts": None, "username": "xxxx", "client_keys": "~/.ssh/dask" },
worker_options={"nthreads": 2},
scheduler_options={"port": 0, "dashboard_address": ":8797"})
client = Client(cluster)
```

**Getting error**

```
 File "/home/naveen/anaconda3/envs/dask_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncssh/connection.py", line 218, in _connect
    await conn.wait_established()
  File "/home/naveen/anaconda3/envs/dask_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncssh/connection.py", line 2096, in wait_established
    await self._waiter
asyncssh.misc.PermissionDenied: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you able to do a ```ssh 192.168.1.2```?

Comment: @DylanFouche sorry please take it as 192.168.x.x ... Just an example

Answer (score 1):

`client_keys` must be a list and point to the private key file!

From the docs:

> A list of keys to use to authenticate this client via host-based authentication.
> The simplest option is to pass the name of a file to read one or more private keys from.

More information on all options can be found [here](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asyncssh.SSHClientConnectionOptions) and [here](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#specifyingprivatekeys).

Here is the updated code:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, SSHCluster

cluster = SSHCluster(
    ["localhost", "192.168.x.x"],
    connect_options={
        "known_hosts": None,
        "username": "xxxx",
        "client_keys": ["~/.ssh/dask/id_rsa"], # <--- HERE!
    },
)

client = Client(cluster)
```

In my opinion the user experience and error management of `asyncssh.connect` (and as an extension `SSHCluster`) could be better in this regard.